# Qual a forma mais peformática pra declarar array em JS?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho observado muito as pessoas declararem arrays da seguinte maneira

```
monthShort : 'Jan_Fev_Mar_Abr_Mai_Jun_Jul_Ago_Set_Out_Nov_Dez'.split('_')
```

Mas também tenho observado utilizarem assim:

```
monthShort : ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
```

Então, existe alguma diferença performática? Se sim, qual? Grato :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro que neste tipo de questões se tenha em consideração que:

- Por vezes esse tipo de testes dão resultados diferentes em browsers diferentes
- É importante escrever código com semântica correta. Se o código engana em relação àquilo que faz, é preferivel a maneira mais correta semânticamente.
- As diferênças de performance só são relevantes em casos em que haja milhares de contas sobre o mesmo processo. Na maior parte das vezes não se nota a diferênça.

Nos testes que fiz (Chrome no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb9Lku01/) e [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/array-performance-sopt)) a maneira mais rápida é a maneira mais semântica. No jsPerf a diferênça é quase irrelevante.

```
monthShort : ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
```